# how to get Signature Image in bitmap

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout mContent;
    signature mSignature;
    Button mClear, mGetSign, mCancel;
    public static String tempDir;
    public int count = 1;
    public String current = null;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    View mView;
    File mypath;

    private String uniqueId;
    private EditText yourName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.signature);
        uniqueId = "Sign" + Math.random();
        current = uniqueId + ".png";
        mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mSignature = new signature(this, null);
        mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mContent.addView(mSignature, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        mClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        mGetSign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getsign);
        mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
        mCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        mView = mContent;

        mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
                boolean error = captureSignature();
                if (!error) {
                    mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    mSignature.save(mView);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("status", "done");
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.w("GetSignature", "onDestory");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private boolean captureSignature() {

        boolean error = false;
        String errorMessage = "";

        if (error) {
            Toast toast = Toast
                    .makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 105, 50);
            toast.show();
        }

        return error;
    }
```

This is signatureView class

```
public class signature extends View {
            private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
            private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
            private Paint paint = new Paint();
            private Path path = new Path();

            private float lastTouchX;
            private float lastTouchY;
            private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

            public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
            }

            public void save(View v) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
                Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
                if (mBitmap == null) {
                    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mContent.getWidth(),
                            mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                    ;
                }
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
                try {
                    FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

                    v.draw(canvas);
                    mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
                    mFileOutStream.flush();
                    mFileOutStream.close();
                    String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                            mBitmap, "title", null);
                    Log.v("log_tag", "url: " + url);
                    // In case you want to delete the file
                    // boolean deleted = mypath.delete();
                    // Log.v("log_tag","deleted: " + mypath.toString() + deleted);
                    // If you want to convert the image to string use base64
                    // converter

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
                }
            }

            public void clear() {
                path.reset();
                invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                float eventX = event.getX();
                float eventY = event.getY();
                mGetSign.setEnabled(true);

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                    lastTouchX = eventX;
                    lastTouchY = eventY;
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                    int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                    for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
                        float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                        float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                        expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                        path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                    }
                    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                    break;

                default:
                    debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
                    return false;
                }

                invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                        (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                        (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                        (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

                lastTouchX = eventX;
                lastTouchY = eventY;

                return true;
            }

            private void debug(String string) {
            }

            private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY) {
                if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left) {
                    dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
                } else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right) {
                    dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
                }

                if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top) {
                    dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
                } else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom) {
                    dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
                }
            }

            private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY) {
                dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
                dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
                dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
                dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
            }
        }
```

I want save  Signature image in Bitmap Currently i am able to show popup and take Signature in that But i dont know  how to get it in Bitmap so that i can save in database .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one.It return passing view as Bitmap

```
 //where view can be any view.
 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    //Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null)
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

and call it in necessary place like.

```
    mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
           //where result is a bitmap which holds passed mView as Bitmap                 
          Bitmap result=getBitmapFromView(mView);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: can u please tell me  i have to get that value on Save Button ?

Comment: Whether you print the bitmap as bytes in log

Comment: Thanx i am getting value

Answer (score 1):

You can get the bitmap using

```
 Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)yourView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      public class CaptureFragment extends FragmentActivity {


    LinearLayout mContent;
    signature mSignature;
    Button mClear, mGetSign, mCancel;
    public static String tempDir;
    public int count = 1;
    public String current = null;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    View mView;
    String upLoadServerUri = null;
    File mypath;


    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private String uniqueId;
    private EditText yourName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.signature);

        tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir) + "/";
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir(getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prepareDirectory();
        uniqueId = getTodaysDate() + "_" + getCurrentTime() + "_" + Math.random();
        current = uniqueId + ".png";
        mypath= new File(directory,current);
        //Toast.makeText(CaptureSignature.this, "Path"+mypath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mSignature = new signature(this, null);
        mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mContent.addView(mSignature, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        //mClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
        mGetSign = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getsign);
        mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
        //mCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        mView = mContent;

        //yourName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourName);

       /* mClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
             finish();
            }
        });*/

        mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
                boolean error = captureSignature();
                if(!error){
                    mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    mSignature.save(mView);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("status", "done");
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

        /*mCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Canceled");
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("status", "cancel");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            }
        });*/


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.w("GetSignature", "onDestory");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private boolean captureSignature() {

        boolean error = false;
        String errorMessage = "";
/*  if(yourName.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            errorMessage = errorMessage + "Please enter your Name\n";
            error = true;
        }*/



        if(error){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 75, 50);
            toast.show();
        }

        return error;
    }

    private String getTodaysDate() {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int todaysDate =     (c.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 10000) +
                ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) * 100) +
                (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        Log.w("DATE:", String.valueOf(todaysDate));
        return(String.valueOf(todaysDate));

    }

    private String getCurrentTime() {

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentTime =     (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 10000) +
                (c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 100) +
                (c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        Log.w("TIME:", String.valueOf(currentTime));
        return(String.valueOf(currentTime));

    }
    private boolean prepareDirectory()
    {
        try
        {
            if (makedirs())
            {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not initiate File System.. Is Sdcard mounted properly?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean makedirs()
    {
        File tempdir = new File(tempDir);
        if (!tempdir.exists())
            tempdir.mkdirs();

        if (tempdir.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] files = tempdir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files)
            {
                if (!file.delete())
                {
                    System.out.println("Failed to delete " + file);
                }
            }
        }
        return (tempdir.isDirectory());
    }

    public class signature extends View
    {
        private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
        private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private Path path = new Path();
        private float lastTouchX;
        private float lastTouchY;
        private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();
        public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
        {
            super(context, attrs);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        }
        public void save(View v)
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
            Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
            if(mBitmap == null)
            {
                mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;
            }
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            try {
                FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
                v.draw(canvas);
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
                mFileOutStream.flush();
                mFileOutStream.close();
                // String url = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
                //  Log.v("log_tag", "url: " + url);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL    :"+mypath.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //new UploadImage().execute(null);
                //changeStatus();
                // uploadImage();
                //In case you want to delete the file
                //boolean deleted = mypath.delete();
                //Log.v("log_tag","deleted: " + mypath.toString() + deleted);
                //If you want to convert the image to string use base64 converter

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
            }
        }
        public void clear()
        {
            path.reset();
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            mGetSign.setEnabled(true);

            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                    lastTouchX = eventX;
                    lastTouchY = eventY;
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                    int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                    for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++)
                    {
                        float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                        float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                        expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                        path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                    }
                    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                    break;

                default:
                    debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
                    return false;
            }

            invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                    (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

            lastTouchX = eventX;
            lastTouchY = eventY;

            return true;
        }

        private void debug(String string){
        }

        private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY)
        {
            if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left)
            {
                dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
            }
            else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right)
            {
                dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
            }

            if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top)
            {
                dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
            }
            else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom)
            {
                dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
            }
        }

        private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY)
        {
            dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
            dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
            dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
            dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That i did alredy but   i have to  get  BitMapvalue  mGetSign   U got it ?